# Will it be safe to use JDK8 in commercial products?

Tags: java, java-8

***I asked this question on Dec 11 '13 and now this question is no longer valid.***

Some of the important dates for JDK 1.8 -

2013/09/05  Developer Preview

2014/01/23  Final Release Candidate

2014/03/18  General Availability

Will it be safe to start development with JDK 1.8 in a commercial product now? Though, it's still in developer preview phase, definitely be for testing purposes. Or should I wait for it's general availability release?

In future, main issue will arise when systems get updated with newer releases of JRE's and then some of the API will be deprecated if development starts with JDK 1.7. This may tend to misbehavior of the system processing.

Comment: If your product doesn't go for production, it's ok. But If I was in your position I would have waited till final release to use in production application. _API will be deprecated if development starts with JDK 1.7_ I feel there will not be a problem because Java has a big backward compatability.

Comment: I would continue to write to JDK 7 but unit test/compile test against JDK 8 releases as they happen. Then if the release slips it won't affect your project.

Comment: Deprecated methods usually stick around for at least 1 additional major release, if not longer. At this point in JDK8, I believe there is a major change freeze so no new api's should be built and no api's should be removed - basically just refining things. I wouldn't use JDK8 in a "production" app just yet unless I was able to deploy my app with the jre embedded (like you can with install4j, advancedinstaller, exec4j, etc)

Comment: i would say yes, but only if commercial availability will be after the GA release. also be sure to read the EULA, and any licensing information. think it is against the eula to release a commercial product with java8 now.

Comment: @aepurniet java8 is a standard, nobody can forbid you from using it.

Comment: @SnakeDoc have you been following google v oracle? and yes they can, when you download the compiler, you specifically agree to the terms of the EULA.

Comment: @aepurniet I'm sure you are aware that Oracle does not control Java nor the specification? They sit on the council, but do not own java. the lawsuits were because google copy/pasted parts of the jdk that were sub-licences from other companies (which oracle kindly pays licensing fees for us all). That's not even an issue with Java 8 because OpenJDK8 Project made it so they are now upstream to Oracle's release, so no copywritten code exists in there anymore. Plus, Oracel's Java download is not the only JDK/JRE in town. So ya, you can use the Java 8 spec however you want, whenever you want.

Comment: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/12/05/google_oracle_appeals_court/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42972/discussion-between-aepurniet-and-snakedoc)

Comment: There have been issues as recently as 4 weeks ago (before build 115) where you could copy/paste (i.e. clipboard interaction) got broken. That can be a major problem depending on what your application does. Now that sort of bug is typically fixed within days and I have not found any major issues with b115 and following. In the end, it depends on how critical and complex your application is.

Answer (score 7):

If it's a server app: do you control the server environment? If so, then JDK 8 is an easy yes. In other scenarios, the customer dictates that a product must run on a specific JDK, in which case you can't just break that.

If it's a consumer app: you can always included a JRE in which case you can use whatever version you want. If you need to use the system JRE for some reason, then you probably can't.

JDK 8 is generally very stable from what I've seen and it's a big improvement over JDK 7.

Comment: +1 for suggesting embedding the jre in your product.

Comment: +1. Any suggestions for why it is better now?

Comment: That's easy. map/flatMap/filter on the collections. Lambdas: passing functions around was possible before, but much, much nicer in 8. Those are huge. LOTS of other stuff too

Comment: According to specifications, we cannot embed JRE that is reason why I asked some suggestions here. Is there any possible way to update code according to JRE specifications?